# How to let StringTemplate.NET to load template files with the extension ".dwt"?

Tags: .net, stringtemplate

The default template file extension of StringTemplate is ".st". Now I have several template files in a folder and their file extension is ".dwt". Is there a way to change the default template file extension and load all of them like below:

```
StringTemplateGroup group = new StringTemplateGroup("views", viewPath);
```

Comment: Isn't StringTemplate _java_, not .NET?

Comment: @Oded: See http://www.stringtemplate.org/download.html ...

Comment: Hi tanascius,

I have read the offical document of StringTemplate. But I can't find a place to introduce how to change the default template file extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rather big hack that might work is to copy all the templates to a temp directory, but with the correct default extension type.